# Delphi client that runs like it is connected to a web server - without a web server. Is it possible?

Tags: delphi

I am familiar with programming in Delphi stand-alone applications and web-server applications.

Is it possible to have a Delphi application that when launched gets the browser to handle its output? Without a server being between the user and the application.

The reason I would like to do this is because HTML CSS and so on provide a more familiar user-interface to most people.

Comment: Why not just distribute the web server application along with a bookmark shortcut to the localhost URI?  Users just want an icon to click - it doesn't have to be an application.

Comment: _Is it possible to have a Delphi application that when launched gets the browser to handle its output_ ? Do you mean Delphi's Output , open the default Browser and show content generated by an Application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not "let the browser handle its output" without any HTTP connection, so a local web server, then using regular URIs like `http://localhost:888/myDelphiApp/FullURI`.

What you can is *to embed a Web Browser to your Delphi application*, then provide the generated web content not via HTTP, but as local content.

You may use

- [THtmlViewer Open Source component](https://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer/) - which I like very much;
- [Delphi Chromium Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded);
- [WebBrowser Component](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27843).

All recognize CSS and HTML content.

Comment: This seems like a silly approach...maybe I'm not understanding but I think OP wants (ie: needs) to have a delphi web-server application for this to work.  The content seems to need to be interactive and would require a backend application to handle the business logic.  The client application would then just end up being a host to a web browser.  This would still require distributing the web server application so it seems more natural just to navigate to the local web server application from a real web browser. Unless you can roll a web-server and desktop application into one? Is that possible?

Comment: @J... why not? I make many service applications that can be configured via web, incorporated into the service...

Comment: @whosrdaddy  I guess my thinking is that if the entire purpose of the application is to provide a web-based UI, then it doesn't make much sense to make a client application that is, in essence, only a web browser wrapper (one that is, by virtue of the nature of web browser components, not as effective a web browser as an actual web browser - especially when the latter are ubiquitous already).

Comment: @whosrdaddy: apps that are configurable via a web browser run their own embedded web server for the browser to connect to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that's what I was saying, no?

Comment: I think the short answer is "no".

I have already looked at THtmlViewer and WebBrowser and had lots of problems getting them to behave the way I wanted. Adding a local server would complicate things and could clash with something else and so on.